# Adding APNs to my SwiftUI app do I add new application func or do I add didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and didReceiveRemoteNotification to the existing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, apple-push-notifications

I am adding notifications to my SwiftUI app, which already has a AppDelegate with an application function:

```
final class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession,
        options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions
    ) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        
        ...

        return configuration
    }
}
```

I want to add two functions to handle when the app isn't running and the user launches it by tapping the push notification:

```
application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)
```

and when the app is running either in the foreground or the background, the system notifies your app by calling:

```
application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)
```

Do I add these options to the existing application func or do I create two more? If so, what does that look like?

Comment: You question is unclear. How do you plan to “add these options to the existing application func or do I create two more”? If you type “application” in between the last 2 closing curly brackets in your code auto-fill gives to the option to add those functions (individually) to the AppDelegate. They are 3 separate functions in 1 class.

Comment: That's what I was asking and it sounds like your answer is that these are three separate functions within the same class and I don't need to worry about altering the original function w/different options.

Comment: Functions don't have options, arguments yes, but the options part is what is unclear. The 2 `application` lines are function signatures. There is no way to combine these.

Comment: Great. Thank you. The article I was reading was a little unclear on this point.

Comment: Much better to have multiple application functions vs a few with a bunch of options. It just confused me a little.